# Photochemical ligand substitution of metal carbonyls - role of water cooled lamp-jacket?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, carbonyl-complexes

Why, in the photochemical substitution of a ligand in a carbonyl complex, is a water-cooled lamp jacket required to separate the solution and the mercury vapour lamp? It's shown in Figure 22.16 of Atkins' Inorganic Chemistry.

Comment: For the benefit of those without the book you mention, it would help if you could add a description of the experiment in question. And welcome to Chemistry StackExchange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main point is to stop the heat flow from the lamp, while allowing UV through. You want to do photochemistry, not thermochemistry.